# Enqueue Wordpress jQuery after it's been deregistered by a plugin

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm looking after a Wordpress install that makes use of a plugin that deregisters jQuery and replaces it with it's own ancient version. I'm aware of [why loading your own jQuery is irresponsible](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) and would like to use the version of jQuery bundled with Wordpress. I'm currently deregistering the plugin's version of jQuery and enqueuing the Wordpress version. However my approach makes some assumptions about the location and version of jQuery. Is there a better way to do this and ensure things don't break when Wordpress is updated?

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.10.2', false );
```

Comment: Use `includes_url( 'js/jquery/jquery.js' )`

Comment: Might be worth shooting a note to the plugin author too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

And WordPress will know to use the included one.

**Edit:**

You can use:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-core' );
```

Assuming that hasn't also been deregistered by another script. I guess this could run the risk of allowing a plugin to register 'jquery' and for 2 versions of jquery to be loaded, though. Keep an eye out!

Comment: I don't think it works. Dylan has de-registered jquery hook first and didn't register any hook. Therefore simply en-queuing the hook will throw an error.

Comment: Hmm, you're quite right.

Comment: I wonder whether using 'jquery-core' would work?

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f48e3f571987adcd6e51c378e05afbb475e6b3c8/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L145

Comment: @James Kemp Thanks, that works. Please edit your answer and I'll accept it. Cheers, Dylan.

Comment: Edited, also added a potential issue using that method.

Comment: It would but you may not get all you want from just the core!. In my view you simply have to register jquery hook just like Dylan did. The culprit here is the plugin.

Comment: Quite, plugins should never really register their own version of jQuery. Would be worth asking the plugin author to change it!